# Can I sort an arraylist that is contained inside a hashmap (T)?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, hashmap

I have a hashmap, and it holds Key - String Type - Array of cheese objects:

```
public void testing(){
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<cheese>> one = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<cheese> two = new ArrayList<>();

    cheese seven = new cheese("59");
    cheese eight = new cheese("60");
    cheese nine = new cheese("12");
    cheese ten = new cheese("15");

    two.add(seven);
    two.add(eight);
    two.add(nine);
    two.add(ten);

    one.put("hello", two);

}
```

This is my cheese class:

```
public class cheese {

    String num;

    public cheese(String num){
        this.num = num;
    }


    public String getString(){
        return num;
    }
}
```

I want to get the ArrayList and sort each element inside the ArrayList, then put the objects back into the hash map.

This is java.I know it already sounds crazy but interesting too!

I thought about using Comparators, and TreeMaps but they seem like they wouldn't suit this problem.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you can sort the list directly when it's in the map; you can just do `Collections.sort(one.get("hello"))`.

Comment: Tried that one, it doesn't work because the things in the array are cheese objects T_T, if they were integer or string values then it works fine :) Thanks for the reply

Comment: then call `Collections.sort(one.get("hello"), thisCheeseComparatorIJustWrote)`.

Comment: i see one trouble in this solution it's using String for numbers. you need to cast it to a number type anyway cuz a lexicographic sort is used for Strings. not sure that you need it.

Comment: @GDT Please don't forget to review the answers and pick one of them which helped to solve your problem. Cheers!

Comment: @CaptainFogetti How do I pick? I tried to up vote your answer but I needed 15 rep

Comment: @GDT You should see a big 'Nike' sign on the left side of every answer. You can just simply click the one next to your favorite answer. I think you don't need reputation for that. You can read more about answers below: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to do is extending your `Cheese` class to implement the `Comparable<Cheese>` interface.

But this assumes that your `Cheese` instances can constitute a total order. If you don't know what is a total order I would suggest learn more about ordering first.

The basic features that your comparable class should possess:

- Reflexivity
- Anti-symmetry
- Transitivity

You can read more about this at the following link:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/

Basically when your `Cheese` class implements the `Comparable` interface it inherits the method `public int compareTo(T o);`. You have to implement this method and return a negative integer or 0 or a positive integer based on the state of your `Cheese` instance according that the compared `Cheese` instance is smaller or equal or bigger in your total ordering.

If you only have one instance field in `Cheese` like in your example, that is the `num` field you can write something along these lines:

```
public class Cheese implements Comparable<Cheese> {

    String num;

    public Cheese(String num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return num;
    }

    public int compareTo(Cheese that) {
        return this.num.compareTo(that.num);
    }
}
```

Note that this is a somewhat degenerate (or lucky?) case, since the state of your `Cheese` class depends only on a single `String`. So in this case deciding which one is smaller, equal or bigger can be easily done by comparing the `num` field. On the other hand if you later extend your class with other fields, then you should be prepared to modify your `compareTo` method to take those fields also into account and keep the class follow the features of total ordering.

One good practice to keep your class under control to write unit tests for all 3 features (reflexivity, anti-symmetry, transitivity) which will fail when you add new fields and your `compareTo` method violates total ordering.

Also if you have a single `String` field than I would also consider using strings to represent cheese.

Probably sorting doesn't work for you because your class didn't implement `Comparable` before.

As an alternative to the `Comparable`, you might also want to implement the `Comparator` interface, in this way you can detach the different cheese sorting strategies from the actual `Cheese` class.

---

EDIT: showing how to accomplish your goal

So you say that

> I want to get the ArrayList and sort each element inside the
>   ArrayList, then put the objects back into the hash map

Then you can do it like this (using my `Cheese` class above):

```
public void testing(){
        HashMap<String, List<Cheese>> one = new HashMap<>();
        List<Cheese> two = new ArrayList<>();

        Cheese seven = new Cheese("59");
        Cheese eight = new Cheese("60");
        Cheese nine = new Cheese("12");
        Cheese ten = new Cheese("15");

        two.add(seven);
        two.add(eight);
        two.add(nine);
        two.add(ten);

        System.out.println(two);
        assert "59".equals(two.get(0).num);
        assert "60".equals(two.get(1).num);
        assert "12".equals(two.get(2).num);
        assert "15".equals(two.get(3).num);

        Collections.sort(two);

        System.out.println(two);
        assert "12".equals(two.get(0).num);
        assert "15".equals(two.get(1).num);
        assert "59".equals(two.get(2).num);
        assert "60".equals(two.get(3).num);
        one.put("hello", two);
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that a solution is to make my cheese class Comparable, when I have done that I will be able to apply a sorting method. And the three things that a class must be for it to be considered Comparable is, Reflexivity, Anti-Symmetry, and Transitivity. Still a bit unsure of how to actually apply this concept(write the code) :(. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I am suggesting. I will update my answer to show how to sort and update the HashMap.

Comment: Thank you Fogetti!, I won't 'forgetti' this :)

Comment: @GDT There is one more thing to watch out for. The current implementation orders the cheese lexicographically. This might be or might not be what you want based on your requirements. If you want to order the cheese by their numeric order, than I would suggest using an `Integer` field instead of the `String` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get an array from the hashMap and sort it using Arrays.sort. No need to put it back, the hashmap already has a reference. Using a treeset instead of array would remove the need for sorting each time an element is added. A treeset is a Set so duplicates would not be allowed if that is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've provided a minimal example. Otherwise you could just have sorted the list before putting it into the `Map`.

With that said, you can change mutable value types directly in a `Map` without any issues.

So code like the following is perfectly fine:

```
Map myMap = one.get("hello");
sortMyMap(myMap);
```

This will result in the list inside the map to be sorted (assuming that `sortMyMap` sorts the element in place).

If the value element in the map is immutable, you can just overwrite it with a new `put`:

```
Map myMap = one.get("hello");
Map mySortedMap = sortMyMap(myMap);
one.put("hello", mySortedMap);
```

Note that in this example, I assume that `sortMyMap` creates a new, sorted, map that it returns.

Comment: What feature about the Map allows me to 'ignore' the object type cheese so I can then sort? and Can I have an example?

Answer (score 0):

There. These 2 lines will sort all your `ArrayLists`.

```
for(String key: one.keySet()) {
    Collections.sort(one.get(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a one liner:

```
one.values().forEach(l -> l.sort(Comparator.comparing(cheese::getString)));
```

This means, invoke `sort()` on each `List<cheese>` stored as a value in the map named `one`, using the result of the `cheese` object's `getString()` method to order the list elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement Comparator in you Cheese class like:

```
public class Cheese implements Comparator<Cheese>{

String num;

public Cheese(String num){
    this.num = num;
}

public Cheese() {

}

public String getCheese(){
    return num;
}

@Override
public int compare(Cheese o1, Cheese o2) {

    return o1.getCheese().compareTo(o2.getCheese());
}
```

and then in your testing() method, before - one.put("hello", two); 
you can write

```
Collections.sort(two, new Cheese());
one.put("hello", two);
```

I think you'll get your sorted ArrayList inside the HashMap. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Sohal Rana, finally solve the problem. Your solution played a big part in it, will post the solution tomorrow evening after work! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer, thanks guys;

```
public class one {

public void testing(){
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<cheese>> one = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<cheese> two = new ArrayList<>();

    two.add(new cheese("59"));
    two.add(new cheese("70"));
    two.add(new cheese("65"));
    two.add(new cheese("25"));
    one.put("hello", two);

    System.out.println(one.get("hello"));

    Collections.sort(two, new Comparator<cheese>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(cheese o1, cheese o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o1.getCheese().compareTo(o2.getCheese());
        }

    });

    System.out.println(one.get("hello"));
}

public String RemovingThe(){

    String tmp = "^(?:The)\\s(.+)$";

    Pattern a = Pattern.compile(tmp);
    Matcher b = a.matcher(" he cat in the hat");


    if(b.find()){
    return b.group(1);
    }else{
    String nop = "no";
    return nop;

    }


}

public static void main (String args[]){
    one two = new one();
    two.testing();
    System.out.println(two.RemovingThe());
    }
}
```

\\\\\\\\\\onetwothree//////////////////

```
public class cheese{

String num;

public cheese(String num){
    this.num = num;
}


public String getCheese(){
    return num;
}

public String toString(){
    return num;
}

public void setCheese(String num){
    this.num = num;
}



}
```